# Приложение Android для связи с БД mysql

Tags: java, android, база-данных, insert

Приложение должно запускаться на старых аппаратах api 19 и выше.
Есть несколько скриптов на php 7. Как их встроить в приложение и извлекать\заносить данные?
Сколько "видеоуроков" не смотрел нечего не выходит, то ли устаревшие, то со мной проблемы.

Это подключение.

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','rotokan123rot');
define('DB','auto_to_db');

//ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' indentified with mysql_native_password BY 'rotokan123rot':

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ('Unable to Connect');

if(!$con)
{
echo 'Connection error == '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
echo "OK";
}

//?>
```

Получение ид и номера, для того чтобы их засунуть в спиннер(комбобокс???).

```
<?php
require_once('c.php');
//require_once('LandP.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUES_METHOD'] = 'GET'){
$sql = "SELECT id_car,goverment_num FROM `cars`";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result, array('id_car'=>$row[0],'goverment_num'=>$row[1]));
}
echo json_encode(array("ID_and_Num"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
}
//?>
```

Скрипт на добавление записи.

```
<?php
require_once('c.php');
//require_once('Log_and_Pass.php');
$1=$_POST['data_of_entry'];
$2=$_POST['value'];
$3=$_POST['iduser1'];
$4=$_POST['idcar'];
$5=$_POST['desCC'];
$6=$_POST['enable'];
$sql="insert into mileages (data_of_entry,value,iduser1,idcar,desCC,enable) values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)";
//$sql="insert into mileages (data_of_entry,value,iduser1,idcar,desCC,enable) values ('1999-12-12','0','1','1','---','1')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
//$response[message]="Yes";
echo "Access";
}
else
{
//$response[message]="No";
echo "Fail";
}
mysqli_close($con);
//?>
```

Ранее уже предлагали такой вариант, он поддерживается api 24 и выше, просто открывает страничку в браузере.

```
String phpUri = "http://......";
Uri address = Uri.parse(phpUri);
Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
startActivity(openlink);
```

Comment: а Вам именно php обязателен? Я бы предложил посмотреть в сторону room

Comment: Нет конечно.

Приму любое решение, которое запуститься при моих скудных навыках и которое запуститься на утюге.

Я просто смотрел как остальные это делают, то php, то jdbc, то ещё как-то...